# Consuming JSON in play! framework controller

Tags: java, javascript, json, playframework

I'm trying to consume a JSON array I created using JavaScript but the array is never bound in my controller

Here is the JavaScript code I use to call my controller action

```
$.post("/produits_ajax",{filterParams:[{name:"milk", value:"chevre"}, {name:"pate", value:"molle"}]},
function(data){
    $('.dynamicContent').html(data);
slideProducts();
// initialize scrollable
$(".scrollable").scrollable();

});
```

My routes file entry

```
POST        /produits_ajax       Application.produitsAjax
```

Here is how I receive it in my play! controller. I'm using play 1.1 and the JsonArray is from com.google.gson.JsonArray

```
public static void produitsAjax(JsonArray filterParams) {
    if(filterParams != null)
        Logger.debug("Le Json: " + filterParams.toString());
    else
        Logger.debug("filterParams is null");

    render();
}
```

As you can imagine I always get "filterParams is null" in my console (I wouldn't be writhing this if I wasn't)

It's very basic so far I just want to bind the array generated in JS to my JsonArray. Play!framework has a great documentation but for some reason there is very little on this particular subject.

If anyone can shed some light on this It would be much appreciated

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just have to create a TypeBinder class to add JsonObject binding capacity to Play!. Actually, that's pretty easy to achieve in Play 1.2. Here's the complete class:

```
@Global
public class JsonObjectBinder implements TypeBinder<JsonObject> {

    @Override
    public Object bind(String name, Annotation[] annotations, String value, Class actualClass, Type genericType) throws Exception {
        return new JsonParser().parse(value);
    }

}
```

That's it! With the @Global annotation, Play will find it at load time and register this with the other binders. I use this in my controller with the following signature :

```
public static void handleJsonBody(JsonObject body) {
    ...
}
```

The body will be automatically parsed by Play. You can do the same for JsonArray to support your particular case.

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options:

- simple one: pass the parameter as a String and in the controller parse it to Json
- complex one: create your own binder using [TypeBinder](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/controllers#play.data.binding.TypeBinder)

Comment: KISS usually work's great for me. So I ended up passing a simple String like this: filterParams:"milk=chevre&pate=molle" and parsing it in the controller using the String.split() method.